# Multiple Markers at this line on listadapter

Tags: android, listview

It says Multiple Markers at this line.I do get errors on the data adapter side how can I solve this..
It says Multiple Markers at this line.I do get errors on the data adapter side how can I solve this..

DataAdapter.java

```
package com.phpserver;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class send1 extends ListActivity {
int ct_id;
String[] ct_name = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    // http post
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8086/city.php");
        // httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
    }
    // convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
        String line = "0";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    // paring data
    JSONArray jArray;
    try {
        jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject json_data = null;
        ct_name = new String[jArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            ct_id = json_data.getInt("CITY_ID");
            ct_name[i] = json_data.getString("CITY_NAME");
        }
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No City Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<string>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ct_name));
    ListView lv;
    lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView                 int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    ct_name[position] + " wasClicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
    }


    });
}
}</string>
```

Comment: Can you please indicate which line?

Comment: the line "setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<string>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ct_name));" should be "setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ct_name));"

Comment: 'setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<string>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,     ct_name));'

Comment: Pro-tip -- read the markers.

Comment: tnx! how about this part it gets errors

 public void onItemClick(AdapterView     int position, long id) {
    // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      ct_name[position] + " wasClicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
      .show();
   }
 
   
  });
 }
}</String>

Comment: I got the codes on this site [link](www.codeproject.com/Tips/289191/Send-and-Recive-Parameter-with-Android-To-Mysql-PH)

Answer (score 0):

Ok..Sorry my tools auto-reformatted your code to my style but here is what I think you need:

```
public class send1 extends ListActivity
{
    int      ct_id;
    String[] ct_name = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String result = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        StringBuilder sb = null;

        // http post
        try
        {
            final HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            final HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8086/city.php");
            // httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            final HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        }
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
        }

        // convert response to string
        try
        {
            final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
            String line = "0";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        }
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // paring data
        JSONArray jArray;
        try
        {
            jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data = null;
            this.ct_name = new String[jArray.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
            {
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                this.ct_id = json_data.getInt("CITY_ID");
                this.ct_name[i] = json_data.getString("CITY_NAME");
            }
        }
        catch (final JSONException e1)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), "No City Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (final ParseException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, this.ct_name));
        ListView lv;
        lv = this.getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> adapter, final View view, final int position, final long id)
            {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                Toast.makeText(send1.this.getApplicationContext(), send1.this.ct_name[position] + " wasClicked",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what was the error.  This code passes sanity check in my eclipse

Comment: I don't know, you could try copying again.  If its complaining so close to the top, then you issue is possible above the class definition in the imports or package line.  Easiest option is make sure the package line is correct and delete all the imports and get your IDE to fix them for you

Comment: will do that actually I get those code on this site [http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/289191/Send-and-Recive-Parameter-with-Android-To-Mysql-PH] can you check this for me?

Comment: Ok, the problem with that code is that its corrupted. there is a "string" that should be "String". a missing parameter in the onItemClick() method and there is an extra </string> at the end

Comment: ok, do you have any reference for "Receiving Parameter with Android To Mysql PHP it must show to a clickable listview" I'm just a newbie in android...

Comment: Try this guy's tutorials http://www.vogella.com/android.html you probably want the XML or JSON ones